# Change the "Local Pickup" text to something else in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

My checkout currently looks like this, with "Local Pickup" enabled in the woocommerce backend:

[image]

Is it possible to change this to, for example, "Pick up from our store"?

The source code for the "shipping" section is:

```
<tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <td data-title="Shipping">
                    <ul id="shipping_method">
                                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method"  />
                                <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1">Standard: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#x62f;.&#x625;</span>30.00</span></label>                 </li>
                                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup2" value="local_pickup:2" class="shipping_method"  checked='checked' />
                                <label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup2">Local pickup: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#x62f;.&#x625;</span>0.00</span></label>                   </li>
                            </ul>


            </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cant you just edit the source html shown?

Comment: the problem with that is if Woo updates the template, it breaks it.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it directly from

Woocommerce => Settings => Shipping Zones => Edit(the Zone name you need the change) => Shipping Methods => Edit ( Local Pickup ) => Change the Label to your need and you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in to your theme (or child theme if you're using it) function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'remove_local_pickup_free_label', 10, 2 );
function remove_local_pickup_free_label($full_label, $method){
    if( $method->id == 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup2' )
    $full_label = str_replace("Local Pickup","Store Pickup",$full_label);
  return $full_label;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately that didn't work - I added the source code in the original question if it helps? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Based on the source you provided, I changed the third line of my answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: For some reason, it still didn't work. I guess woocommerce or my theme must be overriding it somehow... thanks very much for your efforts though!

Comment: Sorry i wasn't of more help.